# vb.net thread every n second

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

The following code is making the Application to hang. No error are showed while debugging.

```
    Private Sub SolarInitBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SolarInitBtn.Click
    Try
        SolarThread = New Thread(SolarThreadStart) With {
        .IsBackground = True,
        .Name = "SolarEnergyUpdateSystem"
    }
        SolarThread.Start()
    Catch myError As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
Public Sub SolarEnergyUpdate()
    Dim Energy As Decimal = SolarStatsLbl.Text
    Dim EnergyMax As Int32 = SolarMaxCapLbl.Text
    If Energy <= EnergyMax Then
        Dim Production As Int32 = SolarProdLbl.Text
        Dim ProdTimeQt As Decimal = FormatNumber(CDec(Production / 3600), 3) + Energy
        EnergyNowLbl.Text = ProdTimeQt
        Thread.Sleep(15000)
    Else
        SolarThread.Abort()
    End If
End Sub
```

What I try is to catch some numbers, do the maths and put the result into  a label, I expected to do that each second or at least for less than 1 minute. Currently the application is hanging. 
I catch for exceptions there is none. (**Using vb.NET**)

Comment: That shouldn't cause your application to hang. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If I remove those lines, the application runs without problems I check it with a timer each second showing the time including seconds

Comment: You are accessing controls directly from a secondary thread. That is a no-no. NEVER access a control directly on any but the UI thread.

Comment: So what if I want to show the result of the maths in a label? How do I do that? Creating the label from the code?

Comment: @Draecal: [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls)

Comment: My guess: how do you update a label every second, when you put the thread to sleep for 15s?

Comment: That was a try I don't mind 1s or 15s